# How to handle duplicates and favor one version but not always

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I have data with duplicated rows per id, because it was collected at two separate time points. I want to remove duplicates and remain with just one row per id, according to the following rule:

For each id, keep the value of the recent time-point, unless the recent is missing (`NA`); in such cases, take the old time-point value. Otherwise, if both time-points are `NA`, then keep one row with `NA`.

### Example data

In this data we have 20 people who were measured twice for their weight.

```r
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), time_point = c("tp1", 
"tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", 
"tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", 
"tp2"), weight = c(56L, NA, 95L, 88L, 61L, NA, 55L, 87L, 87L, 
95L, NA, 96L, 88L, 90L, 72L, NA, NA, 67L, 52L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

> df

##    id time_point weight
## 1   1        tp1     56
## 2   1        tp2     NA
## 3   2        tp1     95
## 4   2        tp2     88
## 5   3        tp1     61
## 6   3        tp2     NA
## 7   4        tp1     55
## 8   4        tp2     87
## 9   5        tp1     87
## 10  5        tp2     95
## 11  6        tp1     NA
## 12  6        tp2     96
## 13  7        tp1     88
## 14  7        tp2     90
## 15  8        tp1     72
## 16  8        tp2     NA
## 17  9        tp1     NA
## 18  9        tp2     67
## 19 10        tp1     52
## 20 10        tp2     NA
```

When we have the two `weight` measures for that person, we go with the "tp2" version, unless "tp2" is `NA` and then we'd go with "tp1". If both happen to be `NA` then we should just keep one row with `NA`.

**Desired output**

```r
##    id time_point weight
## 1   1        tp1     56
## 2   2        tp2     88
## 3   3        tp1     61
## 4   4        tp2     87
## 5   5        tp2     95
## 6   6        tp2     96
## 7   7        tp2     90
## 8   8        tp1     72
## 9   9        tp2     67
## 10 10        tp1     52
```

When I think about solving it using `dplyr`, for example, then I guess it has to include `group_by(id)` and something like `distinct()`. But I don't really know how to get this to work.

---

EDIT

---

I've realized that `df` above is oversimplified example of my real data. In real data, I might have many more columns that need to be handled according to the duplicate removal algorithm I specified.

For example, see `df_2` below:

```r
df_2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), time_point = c("tp1", 
"tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", 
"tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", "tp2", "tp1", 
"tp2"), weight = c(NA, 55L, 86L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 92L, NA, 
71L, 90L, NA, NA, 72L, 93L, 60L, 81L, NA, NA), height = c(NA, 
78L, NA, 92L, 98L, NA, 66L, NA, NA, 73L, NA, NA, NA, 91L, NA, 
NA, NA, 58L, 63L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

> df_2
##    id time_point weight height
## 1   1        tp1     NA     NA
## 2   1        tp2     55     78
## 3   2        tp1     86     NA
## 4   2        tp2     NA     92
## 5   3        tp1     NA     98
## 6   3        tp2     NA     NA
## 7   4        tp1     NA     66
## 8   4        tp2     NA     NA
## 9   5        tp1     92     NA
## 10  5        tp2     NA     73
## 11  6        tp1     71     NA
## 12  6        tp2     90     NA
## 13  7        tp1     NA     NA
## 14  7        tp2     NA     91
## 15  8        tp1     72     NA
## 16  8        tp2     93     NA
## 17  9        tp1     60     NA
## 18  9        tp2     81     58
## 19 10        tp1     NA     63
## 20 10        tp2     NA     NA
```

The expected output would therefore be:

```r
##    id weight height
## 1   1     55     78
## 2   2     86     92
## 3   3     NA     98
## 4   4     NA     66
## 5   5     92     73
## 6   6     90     NA
## 7   7     NA     91
## 8   8     93     NA
## 9   9     81     58
## 10 10     NA     63
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do an `arrange` first and then `slice` after doing a group_by

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   arrange(id, is.na(weight), desc(time_point)) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   slice_head(n = 1) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#      id time_point weight
#   <int> <chr>       <int>
# 1     1 tp1            56
# 2     2 tp2            88
# 3     3 tp1            61
# 4     4 tp2            87
# 5     5 tp2            95
# 6     6 tp2            96
# 7     7 tp2            90
# 8     8 tp1            72
# 9     9 tp2            67
#10    10 tp1            52
```

---

Or after the `arrange`, use `distinct`

```
df %>%
   arrange(id, is.na(weight), desc(time_point)) %>%
   distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#    id time_point weight
#1   1        tp1     56
#2   2        tp2     88
#3   3        tp1     61
#4   4        tp2     87
#5   5        tp2     95
#6   6        tp2     96
#7   7        tp2     90
#8   8        tp1     72
#9   9        tp2     67
#10 10        tp1     52
```

---

If there are more than one column, then we do a group by summarise with `across` on those columns, individually order them based on the NA value and the descending order of 'time_point', get the `first` non-NA element

```
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(across(c(weight), ~ .[order(is.na(.),
          -as.integer(factor(time_point)))][1]), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#      id weight
# * <int>  <int>
# 1     1     56
# 2     2     88
# 3     3     61
# 4     4     87
# 5     5     95
# 6     6     96
# 7     7     90
# 8     8     72
# 9     9     67
#10    10     52
```

---

For the updated dataset 'df_2'

```
df_2 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(across(c(weight, height), ~ .[order(is.na(.),
           -as.integer(factor(time_point)))][1]), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#      id weight height
# * <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1     1     55     78
# 2     2     86     92
# 3     3     NA     98
# 4     4     NA     66
# 5     5     92     73
# 6     6     90     NA
# 7     7     NA     91
# 8     8     93     NA
# 9     9     81     58
#10    10     NA     63
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that I used an oversimplified data example. In real life I have many columns, not just `weight`. But your solution works with just one specific col. Is it possible to have a global version of your solution that would apply this dupe removal on any columns (except for `id`)?

Comment: @Emman May be you can use `arrange(across` if there are more columns

Comment: @Emman Wouldn't that also create some clash. i.e. suppose for id 1, the weight column have first value NA and second column have second value NA, so, which time_point you willl select

Comment: you're right. so we should not include the `time_point` column at the end.

Comment: @Emman updated the solution.  Please check.  Here, in `across` you can have a range of columns or specify the columns individually i..e `across(c(weight, weight2)..` or `across(where(is.numeric),`

Comment: Oh no hold on.... When going by the first non-NA we lost the rule of preferring the "tp2" over the "tp1". I've updated the post with `df_2`

Comment: @Emman Can you show your expected output for `df_2

Comment: just added the expected output. Your final method nailed it. Thank you and sorry for the trouble. My original data was too simple and caused the whole confusion. Thanks again!

Comment: @Emman Glad to know that. Have a great day!

Comment: Just learning the code more deeply, I have a question: Say that I want to change priorities and prefer "tp1" over "tp2", or otherwise say that I have different names (`foo` and `blah`) instead of "tp2" and "tp2", do I need to relevel `time_point` to tweak the priority? I'm trying to generalize this solution to my real data...

Comment: @Emman You can make the change by specifying the `factor(time_point, levels = c("foo", "blah"))` in the order you want it to appear

Answer (score 3):

You can workout the rank of the measurement within the id and keep records with rank of one

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[order(weight, time_point), rn := 1:.N, id]
res <- df[rn == 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Although @akrun's `dplyr` solution is great, I now realize that it's a time costly operation given large datasets. So I'd like to explore the `data.table` option too. Would it be possible to adjust the code here to data with more than 1 column, as `df_2` demonstrates?